# Use another source if external service is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, backup, external

In my project i'm using following small library for interacting with the external serivce:

```
class ExternalServiceInteraction
  include Singleton

    URL = Rails.env.production? ? 'https://first.production.url.com' : 'http://sandbox.url.com'
    API_KEY = Rails.env.production? ? 'qwerty' : 'qwerty'
    DOMAIN = Rails.env.production? ? 'prod.net' : 'stage.net'

  def connection
    conn = Faraday.new(url: URL) do |faraday|
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
  end

  def return_response(item=true)
    if @resp.status == 200
      response = item ? Hash.from_xml(@resp.body)['xml']['item'] : Hash.from_xml(@resp.body)['xml']
    else
      response =  Hash.from_xml(@resp.body)['xml']['error']
      Rails.logger.info "response_error=#{response}"
    end
    response
  end

  def get_subscribers
    path = 'subscribers'
    data = { 'X-API-KEY' => API_KEY, 'domain' => DOMAIN }
    @resp = connection.get(path, data)
    return_response
  end

  def get_subscriber(physical_id)
    path = 'subscriber'
    data = { 'X-API-KEY' => API_KEY, 'Physical_ID' => physical_id, 'domain' => DOMAIN }
    @resp = connection.get(path, data)
    return_response
  end
  # and so on
end
```

Now i want to use 'https://second.production.url.com' if the there are any error with interacting service via first url, how will be better to setup this?

At first i tried to ping / get 200 ok from server and if this fails, than i switch to the second URL. But there are situations when server is up and running, returns 200 OK, but API isn't reachable. My mains issue is that i don't see how i can catch error and re-run method with another URL from the library.

Comment: you seem to need to define out what `API isn't reachable` means and rerun in those cases. Like returns 200 but 'status=error' possibly?

Comment: I mean `Faraday::Error::Timeout` or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write my own HostBackup Faraday middleware for this case.
You are welcome to use it! https://github.com/dpsk/faraday_middleware
Here is an article: http://nikalyuk.in/blog/2013/06/25/faraday-using-backup-host-for-remote-request/

Answer (score 1):

Create an `ExternalServiceInteractionWithoutFallback` which would accept a URL in the constructor. Then, move all API methods to this one, and in `ExternalServiceInteraction` you catch all API methods with `method_missing` and delegate to an "active" instance of `ExternalServiceInteractionWithoutFallback`, and if the call fails, you change the instance you delegate to.

Comment: Hmmm, not bad solution, but i come up with another one, im trying to add custom faraday middleware that will swap urls for me. Thanks!